# How to set attributed text to UILabel which defined in custom UITableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I am bit trouble with setting attributed text to uilable which is defined in uitableview cell. I am setting attributed text in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method of uitableview but it does not affect on output. I just wanted text of uilabel will display as bold text.
My code is as follow:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 MessagesTable *msgobject=[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"messagingCellText";
    TextTableViewCell *ccell = (TextTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (ccell == nil)
    {
        ccell = [[TextTableViewCell alloc] initMessagingCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier MessageType:msgobject.messageMediaType];
        cell2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell2.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

        cell2.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        cell2.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    }

NSString *newString = "This is Bold, This is regular"; 
 NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString      alloc]initWithString:newString];
 NSRange rangeOfSubstring = [newString rangeOfString:@"This is Bold"];  
 [attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                             value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GandhiSans-Bold" size:16]
                             range:rangeOfSubstring]; 
 ccell.messageLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
 return ccell;
 }
```

And my initMessagingCellWithReuseIdentifier: method is as follows:

```
 -(id)initMessagingCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier MessageType:(NSString *)msgTypePara{
 if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
   /*Message-Label*/
        self.messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        //self.messageLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:messageTextSize];
        self.messageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        self.messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.messageLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        self.messageLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        //self.messageLabel.font=[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
        //self.messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GandhiSans-regular" size:messageTextSize];
        self.messageLabel.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        [self.messageLabel sizeToFit];
        [self addSubview: self.messageLabel];



    [self.contentView addSubview: self.messageView];
 return self;
 }
```

Comment: If whole text has to be bold, it may be better to set the `message.Label.font`. Else, are you sure you didn't change anything else on `message.Label`?

Comment: If you want to use only bold style, why don't you set bold font directly to label?

Comment: No, I wanted to custom text in feature, means some text should display bold and some regular

Comment: Yes, you may use bold style, otherwise check your "GandhiSans-Bold" font family, which is not working properly, becoz, I tested your code with modification of "[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f]" and is working fine...

Comment: Ok, just replace the font with system font, then you can identify the issue

Comment: @SailendraKumar, I tried your code but not working here..

Comment: Is there any other call of `messageLabel` in your code?

Comment: I am not sure but issue is defining uilabel in custom tableview cell and setting attributed text in cellForRowAtIndexPath method..

Comment: @MahiM. please try like this [ccell.messageLabel setAttributedText: [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:newString attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GandhiSans-Bold" size:16]}]];

Comment: Is `messageLabel` nil?

Comment: @SumitGarg tried but no luck..

Comment: @Larme i checked that also but messageLabel is not nil

Comment: It's missing context. You may need to give the whole code of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and potentially log the value of `ccell.messageLabel.attributedText`.

Comment: @Larme see my edited question

Comment: Do you see your label at all? If you do `ccell.messageLabel.text = @"Hello";` do you see hello? It's not clear if you even see the text or not. Because in your code, I'm wondering, since you did `sizeToFit` (with no text), is that your label may be of size (0,0). So if by setting the text you didn't see it, do after setting the attributedText (or text), `[ccell.messageLabel sizeToFit];`

Comment: @Larme, it showing the text whatever given to label, my problem is that it is not showing affects like bold some part of text given in attributed text, instead it is showing plain text.

Comment: Problem is that when i use default label of cell i.e. ccell.textLabel.attributedText = attrstr;  It is works but with custom defined label does not get affected.

Answer (score 0):

try this
     and please replace it with your particular  code  and check is there any change happens

```
NSString *newString = @"This is Bold, This is regular";
    NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString  alloc]initWithString:newString];
    NSRange rangeOfSubstring = [newString rangeOfString:@"This is Bold"];


    [attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                    value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT" size:16]
                    range:rangeOfSubstring];

    [attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                    value:[UIColor redColor]
                    range:rangeOfSubstring];
```

Comment: @mahi i check your code and its fine the only issue is font name  can you please change the font name with  this TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT and it will start working

Comment: @mahi do one  thing i am giving  you one  method for font  name check  please include that method in you  class and check log it will give you all you fonts in system and in xcode  try to use one of them which have bold atribute

Comment: i used system font also but it is not working, i have given my code, just see my edited question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *MylabelAttributes = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"my test"];


[MylabelAttributes addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yourcolor]  range:NSMakeRange(0,MylabelAttributes.length)];
[MylabelAttributes addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                          value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:19.0]
                          range:NSMakeRange(0,MylabelAttributes.length)];

self.yourlabel.attributedText=MylabelAttributes;
```

Comment: Avoid naming var starting with an uppercase. Why the paragraph style or the font color? How is it relevant to the question?

Comment: Thank you. i was so fast on typing.